# Extracting Modulus and Exponent from PGP Public Key

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I am working on an application that implements PGP encryption. I am faced with a issue where we need to extract the Modulus and Exponent from the PGP public keys. I am using [Bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) PGP library. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the the code after selecting the public Key

```
 PgpPublicKey  PublicKey;
 var val = (RsaKeyParameters)PublicKey.GetKey();
 string ModulusVal = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val.Modulus.ToString()));
 string ExponentVal = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val.Exponent.ToString()));
XDocument X = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                                        new XElement("RSAKeyValue",
                                            new XElement("Modulus", ModulusVal),
                                            new XElement("Exponent", ExponentVal)));
X.Save(XMLFileSavePath, SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using X509 Certificates which contains embedded PGP keys. Can you please provide the code for that?